# Draggable elements with connectors in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I want to implement a mapping app with draggable elements. I have used the following code but when the draggable is set, the div element is not draggable, only the anchor is draggable. What am I missing?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/tdmghybt/6/)

```
<style>
.dd{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
        <div id="window3" class="dd" style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:100px"></div>
        <div id="window4" class="dd" style="margin-left:400px;margin-top:100px"></div>
</div>
<script>
    jsPlumb.ready(function () {
        //           



        jsPlumb.draggable($(".dd"));



        var endpointOptions = {
            isSource: true,
            isTarget: true,
            endpoint: ["Dot", {
                radius: 10
            }],
            style: {
                fillStyle: 'blue'

            },
            maxConnections: -1,
            connector: "Straight",
            connectorStyle: {
                lineWidth: 3,
                strokeStyle: 'black'

            },
            scope: "blackline",
            dropOptions: {
                drop: function (e, ui) {
                    alert('drop!');
                }
            }
        };
        var window3Endpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint('window3', {
            anchor: "Right"
        }, endpointOptions);
        var window4Endpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint('window4', {
            anchor: "Left"
        }, endpointOptions);




    });
</script>
```

using jQuery draggable allows the div to be draggable but then the anchors become detached.

So the two options are

1. Use **$(".dr").draggable()** and find a way to bind anchors to the div
2. Make the div draggable in **jsPlumb.draggable()**

Or is my approach completely wrong?

**UPDATE:** I set the CSS position as absolute in the divs and now the divs are draggable but still the binding is faulty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to invoke `jsPlumb.repaintEverything()` once the DOM element is dragged.

Here is the version which uses `jQuery.draggable()`

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {

  $('.dd').draggable({
        //listen for element dragged event
        drag: function(){
           jsPlumb.repaintEverything();            
        }
  });


  var endpointOptions = {
    isSource: true,
    isTarget: true,
    endpoint: ["Dot", {
      radius: 10
    }],
    style: {
      fillStyle: 'blue'

    },
    maxConnections: -1,
    connector: "Straight",
    connectorStyle: {
      lineWidth: 3,
      strokeStyle: 'black'

    },
    scope: "blackline",
    dropOptions: {
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        alert('drop!');
      }
    }
  };
  var window3Endpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint('window3', {
    anchor: "Right"
  }, endpointOptions);
  var window4Endpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint('window4', {
    anchor: "Left"
  }, endpointOptions);

});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/tdmghybt/8/)

Comment: If I want to add the same functionality for dynamically created elements(Say new elements are appended when user clicks a button), I would have to invoke the repaint function ?

Comment: Yes..you could give the same class to the newly created element..that should take care of repaint as well